# Vector arrow on top of an letter as char or String

Tags: java, string, unicode, char, ascii

Is there a possibility to add a letter with a vector arrow on top to a string (in Java), like the image shows below?
With an special ASCII code or something?

[image]

Comment: To be clear, Java doesn't use ASCII.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use ['COMBINING RIGHT ARROW ABOVE' (U+20D7)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20d7/index.htm) code point:

```
System.out.println("a\u20D7");
```

It should be displayed as a⃗ but some fonts might not render it correctly.

The concept of combining characters is described [in the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character):

> In digital typography, combining characters are characters that are intended to modify other characters. The most common combining characters in the Latin script are the combining diacritical marks (including combining accents).
>
> Unicode also contains many precomposed characters, so that in many cases it is possible to use both combining diacritics and precomposed characters, at the user's or application's choice. This leads to a requirement to perform Unicode normalization before comparing two Unicode strings and to carefully design encoding converters to correctly map all of the valid ways to represent a character in Unicode to a legacy encoding to avoid data loss.
>
> In Unicode, the main block of combining diacritics for European languages and the International Phonetic Alphabet is U+0300–U+036F. Combining diacritical marks are also present in many other blocks of Unicode characters. In Unicode, diacritics are always added after the main character (in contrast to some older combining character sets such as ANSEL), so it is possible to add several diacritics to the same character, although as of 2010, few applications support correct rendering of such combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can save it either of them either char or String because java takes 2 bytes for each char and support Unicode(UTF-16) char (Since java 9, java is using compact string implementation which helps java to identify the char type either ASCII or UNICODE and accordingly java is taking 1 or 2 bytes for each char).

Moreover, You can store any char of the world inside java char/string like Chinese, Japanese etc as it supports UTF-16.

Comment: I think you missunderstood my question a little bit, but thanks anyway, good to now!

Comment: Compact string storage is for strings entirely with characters that are in [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) and C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement blocks; not "ASCII". It should be noted that it is an internal implementation issue. The String API is always the same: a String is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units.